# How can I increase the limit or get data from next resultpage using the facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting events from a page and noticed some were missing, this is because they are not in the first result but on another "page" (in the graph api explorer tool I can click 'next' at the bottom of my result.

How can I loop through everything there is?

Do I first need to create a loop for how many pages there are, and then create 1 big object/array containing all data?

Currently I have the following:

```
$json_object = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/mypageid/events?fields=owner,start_time,cover,description,name,place&access_token=mytoken");

$feedarray = json_decode($json_object);

$f = 0;

$facebookfeed = '';
//Reversing to show newest events first
$facebookevents = array_reverse($feedarray->data);

foreach ($facebookevents as $key => $feed_data)
{
loop here
}
```

I tried to find out what changes when clicking on another page, but the only parameters that are added are: `pretty=0` and `limit=25` but this is the same on every page I click. Changing the limit does not work if I increase it.

How can I get ALL my data in one object/array?

Comment: The next and prev links are present already in the data structure you get back (when applicable), so all you need to do is make the next request using those URLs as-is.

Comment: And if you want to get more results in one request - well then specify the limit to begin with ... `?fields=...&limit=100` (100 is the upper limit IIRC, for some endpoints it might be lower.)